# Actions to use when flushing cache (when posts are added / deleted / modified)

Tags: posts, cache, actions

I'm looking for a list of action tags that are relevant when you:

- create a post, with any method, so basically using wp_insert_post
- modify a post, like changing status, title, content, terms, meta, anything related to it;
- remove a post

Are `save_post` and `deleted_post` enough for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 'save_post' and 'delete_post' cover everything, except modifying meta and terms associated to a post. Those hooks can be found in wp-includes: `meta.php` and `taxonomy.php`, respectively.

Comment: so the other ones would be: `added_post_meta`, `updated_post_meta`, `deleted_post_meta` and `added_term_relationship`, `deleted_term_relationships` ?

Comment: @One Trick Pony: Yep.